# App crashing when firebase database child node is removed

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

I have fragment activity called NewRescueRequest that loads values from a database child node.

```
 databaseReference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            RequestEntries requestEntries = dataSnapshot.getValue(RequestEntries.class);
            requestfirstname.setText(requestEntries.getRequestFirstName() + " " + requestEntries.getRequestLastName());
            requestcontactnumber.setText(requestEntries.getRequestContactNumber());
            requestlocation.setText(requestEntries.getRequestLocation());
            requestlandmarks.setText(requestEntries.getRequestLandmarks());
```

When the child is moved to a different node, the app crashes. I want to make it go to a different activity when the database child is removed from the node. I tried using ValueEventListener on the onCreateView method.

```
databaseReference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

            }
            else{
                setRequestFragment();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Where is crash logs, post it ?

Comment: why you check for `dataSnapshot.exists()` in second code snippet and not check it in first?

Comment: @M D when the child is removed, it's invoking null pointer exception (java.lang.NullPointerException)

Comment: @VadimEksler i overlooked onto that, i needed to also put dataSnapshot.exist() onto the first one to avoid crashing. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if(dataSnapshot.exists()) must also be included into the first code snippet.